# listview not updated baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, datetime-format

i working baseadapter.
i have two datetimeformat 09/01/2014 and 09/10/2014.i checked days between there datetimes

```
public String getDateDiffString(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo)
{
    long timeOne = dateOne.getTime();
    long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
    long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;

    if (delta > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < delta; i++) {

        }
        return  String.valueOf(delta) ;
    }
    else {
        delta *= -1;
        return String.valueOf(delta);
    }
}
```

and also i wrote funtciton to change there datetimes format 09/01/2014 i changed it 1 Sep

```
public static String dateFormatterforLukka(String inputDate,int lenght) {

    String inputFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    String outputFormat = String.valueOf(lenght)+"MMM";

    Date parsed = null;
    String outputDate = "";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat,
                new Locale("en", "US"));
        SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat,
                new Locale("en", "US"));


        parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
        outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);

        Log.wtf("outputDate", outputDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        outputDate = inputDate;
    }
    return outputDate;
}
```

now i want to  add   my datetimes in listview like this .betweeen days there two datetimes . 1 Sep,2 Sep  etc...

BaseAdapter Code

```
public class HollAdapters extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private final ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems;
private CinemaInfoModel objBean;
private TextView start_time,holle,time;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public HollAdapters(Context context, ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems) {
    mContext = context;

    this.hollitems = hollitems;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return hollitems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;

    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_holl_adapter, null);
    start_time = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.adapter_day);
    holle = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.adapter_holl);
    time = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.adapter_time);
    objBean = hollitems.get(position);

    start_time.setText(objBean.getStartTime());
    holle.setText(objBean.getHole());
    String start_time=objBean.getTime();
    start_time=start_time.replace(",", "\n");
    time.setText(start_time);
    return grid;
}
```

}

this is a main java code

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "MM/dd/yyyy");

                        Date _d = df.parse("09/01/2014");

                        Date _d1 = df.parse("09/10/2014");

                        SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "d MMM");


                        String _s1 = new_df.format(_d1);



                        String datetimeis=getDateDiffString(_d1, _d);
                        Log.wtf("differentis ", datetimeis);                                    
                        int abc=Integer.parseInt(datetimeis);
                        for (int l = 0; l < abc; l++) {
                    String ab = dateFormatterforLukka(timeJsonArray
                                    .getJSONObject(k).getString("start_time"),l++);
                            Log.wtf("timeeeeeeeee", ab);
                            cinemaTime.setStartTime(ab);
                            cinemaTime.setEndTime(_s1);
                            cinemaTimesArray.add(cinemaTime);
                        }
```

when i run my app only 8 sep added always in my listview ,but i loged and in log i have 
[different result](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2rnelow.jpg), meybe listview  did not updated

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: please share adapter code where you use notifydatasetchange();

Comment: @koutuk i added my baseadapter code

Answer (score 1):

Create a methord in adapter class

```
public void setdata(ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems_temp) {
    this.hollitems=hollitems_temp;        
}
```

---

```
for (int l = 0; l < abc; l++) {
   String ab = dateFormatterforLukka(timeJsonArray
                .getJSONObject(k).getString("start_time"),l++);
   Log.wtf("timeeeeeeeee", ab);
   cinemaTime.setStartTime(ab);
   cinemaTime.setEndTime(_s1);
   cinemaTimesArray.add(cinemaTime);
}
```

after this loop i am assuming  that cinematimesarray is of type CinemaInfoModel

```
youradapter.setdata(cinemaTimesArray);
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

put debugger in your getview methord and check;